# PHP equivalent of CryptoJS Base64 encode

Tags: php, base64, cryptojs

My requirement: Replace JavaScript CryptoJS code with PHP code instead.

I have wracked my brain in trying various options with PHP's `base64_encode()` and I'm not getting the result to match the JavaScript `CryptoJS` library result. However the hash results match between JS and PHP, so the issue is the differebase64 encoding. Thank you.

**CryptoJS libraries used**

```
<script src="hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

**CryptoJS**

```
<script>
    // key & phrase
      var SecretKey = 'this is the key';
      var phrase = 'this is the phrase';

    // Hash it
      var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(phrase, SecretKey);  // CryptoJS hash result: 239ab12c89ca09707106c45e78cc5e7a320134c8323d2c971ab2cf3130b5256e
      // IT MATCHES!

    // Base64 encode it
      var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);  // base64 result: I5qxLInKCXBxBsReeMxeejIBNMgyPSyXGrLPMTC1JW4=
      // DOES NOT MATCH - PROBLEM HERE

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// key & phrase
  $SecretKey = 'this is the key';
  $phrase = 'this is the phrase';

// Hash it
  $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $phrase, $SecretKey);   // CryptoJS hash result: 239ab12c89ca09707106c45e78cc5e7a320134c8323d2c971ab2cf3130b5256e
  // IT MATCHES!

// Base64 encode it
  $hashInBase64 = base64_encode($hash);   // PHP base64 result: MjM5YWIxMmM4OWNhMDk3MDcxMDZjNDVlNzhjYzVlN2EzMjAxMzRjODMyM2QyYzk3MWFiMmNmMzEzMGI1MjU2ZQ==
  // IT DOES NOT MATCH - PROBLEM HERE
```

Comment: You must pass `true` as 4th parameter in the PHP code when calling [`hash_hmac()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) otherwise the data will be returned hex encoded.

Comment: @Topaco You are a saviour. Thank you! You are welcome to redo your post as an answer, so I can tick it.